# Javascript ,how to remove values before parentheses and also the parentheses it self

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, parentheses

```
 var s = "1236(75)";
 var s = s.replace(/\(|\)/g, '');

 alert (s); // this gives me 123675  


what i actually need is 75

any help will be appreciated!
```

the above code results in 123675, but I need it to return just 75, please help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `^.+` to match everything from the start of the input string.

```
var s = "1236(75)";
var s = s.replace(/^.*\(|\)/g, '');
```

That said, you could use a regex to do the opposite: instead of getting rid of everything you *don't* want, just match the parts you *do* want:

```
var match = s.match(/\((\d+)|\)/)[1];
```

Comment: Your answer requires at least one character before the opening paren. You might want a * instead of +.

Comment: @LeeMeador valid point. Unfortunately, like so many regex questions, the full range of input the code is expected to handle isn't even mentioned, let alone fleshed out. I prefer the second pattern anyway.

Comment: The 2nd one is a problem if 's' doesn't have a parenthesized string in it. The match() call returns null in that case.

Comment: Again, valid point, and again, the OP does not mention whether (and if so, how) or not the code needs to handle such input.

Comment: once more quick question, can the same result be achieved in C#?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var s = s.replace(/.*\(|\)/g, '');
```

But that will only remove leading characters (before the open-paren) and only allow one parenthesized part. Anything after the closing paren will remain.

What you really might want is something to match the string with parens around it and give you back the part inside the parens.

```
var m = /\((.*\))/.exec(s);
if (m) var result = m[1]
```

Then, if there are more parenthesized parts, you can get them with [1] and [2] and so forth.

You can also do something similar with the new regex and 'split()'

Answer (score 0):

if you just need to match the number in parentheses you can do

```
s.match(/\((\d+)\)/)[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove number and the opening bracket from the beginning and the closing bracket from the end:

```
s = s.replace(/^\d*\(/, '').replace(/\)$/, '');
```